# BigQuery overhead of Stored Procedures

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a use case to create some sophisticated search predicates against Google BigQuery. We have built some search screens that use stored procedures that create dynamic sql that is then run using "execute immediate". Here is a completely synthetic example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `somewhere`.author_name_search(
    IN firstNamePrefix STRING,
    IN lastNamePrefix STRING
)
BEGIN
    /* note select '*' is bad practice */
    DECLARE DYNAMIC_SQL STRING DEFAULT 'SELECT * FROM `somewhere_else.author`';
    DECLARE WHERE_CLAUSE STRING DEFAULT '';
 
    IF ASCII(firstNamePrefix) != 0 THEN
        SET WHERE_CLAUSE = WHERE_CLAUSE || " firstName like '" || firstNamePrefix || "%'";
    END IF;
 
    IF ASCII(lastNamePrefix) != 0 THEN
        IF ASCII(WHERE_CLAUSE) != 0 THEN
            SET WHERE_CLAUSE = WHERE_CLAUSE || " OR ";
        END IF;  
        SET WHERE_CLAUSE = WHERE_CLAUSE || "lastName like '" || lastNamePrefix || "%'";
    END IF;
 
    /* if there no optional input this is a full table scan which is VERY BAD. you need to partition and force that all search inputs only return some partitions */
    IF ASCII(WHERE_CLAUSE) != 0 THEN
        SET DYNAMIC_SQL = DYNAMIC_SQL || " WHERE " || WHERE_CLAUSE;
    END IF;  
     
    SET DYNAMIC_SQL = DYNAMIC_SQL || " LIMIT 100000";
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE DYNAMIC_SQL;
END;
```

Note that is a really basic example with lots of performance issues. In reality the data is partitioned by date, require partition filter is set to true, the UI suggests a reasonable date range, the UI only select a subset of fields not all of them. Where things get complex is that we have sort column and sort order and up to a dozen optional search input fields which is why we are looking to use dynamic sql with execute immediate within a procedure. We are aware that BigQuery is not built for low latency OLTP queries so we optimize our datasets for these "interactive search" screens and set user expectations that the response times will a few seconds depending on the complexity of the search they are running.

We ran some performance tests comparing the overhead of just querying the underlying table/view as opposed to querying it from within a proc. The simplest test proc is hardcoded to just return some fixed data from a view so that we can do a direct comparison such as:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `somewhere`.author_name_search(
    IN firstNamePrefix STRING,
    IN lastNamePrefix STRING
)
BEGIN
/* not the logic here is not quite identical in reality we are hardcoding the query to return a known result to compare with other test runs */
SELECT * FROM `somewhere_else.author` where firstName like firstNamePrefix OR lastName like lastNamePrefix;
END;
```

The real test proc is more or less hardcoded to pull some exact test rows from the underlying table. If we query the table directly without a proc everything is sub-second end-to-end. When we simply hardcode the same query statement into a minimal stored proc (as above) everything is one whole second slower. So using the proc seems to add a fixed overhead which is more than 100% the full application time when not going via a proc.

It this expected or is there something we can do to tune things so that procs are not a massive overhead?

Comment: i have raised a support case with google about this.

Comment: The overheard is because when executing the dinamyc store procedure, each time you execute the query change, and each time BigQuery generates the cache; if you execute the hardcore query: the first time generates the cache and the second time Bigquery uses the cache for the first execution. 
 
You can see more documentation about overhead: https://www.adoclib.com/blog/whats-causing-so-much-overhead-in-google-bigquery-query.html
 
You can see this document about query planning and performance. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation

Comment: i am executing the second code block which is not dynamic sql it is a hardcoded query and i am running it the same way ten times in a row. i am seeing a >1000ms overhead when BigQuery has an opportunity to cache everything or run it without any cache and when I run the query directly it is subsecond.